# remove element by position in a vector<string> in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have been trying to remove the value `False` and `0;0` from a `vector<string> plan;` containing the following

```
1003;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1678721F
1005;2021-03-05;False;0;0;1592221D
1005;2021-03-06;False;0;0;1592221D
1003;2021-03-07;False;0;0;1592221D
1003;2021-03-08;False;0;0;1592221D
1004;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1592221D
1004;2021-03-10;False;0;0;1592221D
1001;2021-03-11;False;0;0;1592221D
```

but the solutions I have found only work with int, and I tried the following

```
remove(plan.begin(), plan.end(), "False");
```

also with `erase`, but it didn't work

what is the mistake that I am making, or how should I do to eliminate the values that I want, which are in the position `[2]` `[3]` and `[4]`, thanks for any help.

Comment: `plan.erase(plan.begin() + 2, plan.begin() + 4);`?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't remove anything

Comment: May you explicitly show how you defined the <vector> plan? This does not necessarily look like a string vector :)

Comment: I defined it like this `vector<string> planificacionVector;`

Comment: `std::erase_if(cnt, [](const string &x) { return x == "False"; });` ?

Comment: [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b86026a490acf268) of my first comment.

Comment: Please create a proper [mre] to show us. Hard-code the contents of the vector so we see exactly what's in it.

Comment: I feel there is some confusion of terminology going on. What is the type of your vector? Is it `vector< string >`? If it is, each **line** from your dataset is one element, and there is no "element" that is "False". Perhaps write up a [mcve] to clarify.

Comment: Is it `1003;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1678721F` a row in a `vector<string>`? if so [DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/dKLpW4cv_)

Comment: as @Someprogrammerdude points out, one would assume that each line of the content you printed is a string, in that case you would have to loop through each element of the vector.

Comment: Please show us the expected result.

Comment: more information on Jarod42's solution: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Comment: @TruthSeeker code worked, I only changed line 31 to `e.erase (16, 10);` but I wish you could explain it to me or someone explain it to me, I understand the logic a bit, but it's not entirely clear to me, yes It is possible, also why another method did not work, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Note**: With the assumption `1003;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1678721F` corresponding to a row inside `std::vector<string>`]

---

[std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) : Removes from the vector either a single element (position) or a range of elements ([first, last)).

In case `std::vector<string> plan` contains value `False` then it is removed.

```
  std::vector < std::string > plan =
  {
     "1003","2021-03-09","False","0;0","1678721F"
      
  };
  
  std::remove(plan.begin(),plan.end(),"False");
```

---

In your case you need to remove given sub-string from each row of the `plan`. You need to iterate through all the rows to remove given value using [std::string::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

```
  std::vector < std::string > plan =
  {
     "1003;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1678721F",
      "1005;2021-03-05;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1005;2021-03-06;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1003;2021-03-07;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1003;2021-03-08;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1004;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1004;2021-03-10;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1001;2021-03-11;False;0;0;1592221D"};

    for (auto & e:plan)
    {
      //As position of False;0;0; is at a fixed index, i.e: from index:16, 10 characters are removed
      e.erase (16, 10);
    }
```

---

To generalize, You can make use of std::String::find to find a sub-string and erase it.

```
void removeSubstrs(string& s, string p) { 
  string::size_type n = p.length();
  for (string::size_type i = s.find(p);
      i != string::npos;
      i = s.find(p))
      s.erase(i, n);
}

int
main ()
{

  std::vector < std::string > plan =
  {
     "1003;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1678721F",
      "1005;2021-03-05;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1005;2021-03-06;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1003;2021-03-07;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1003;2021-03-08;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1004;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1004;2021-03-10;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1001;2021-03-11;False;0;0;1592221D"};

    for (auto & e:plan)
    {
      removeSubstrs (e, ";False;0;0");
    }
    
    for (auto e:plan)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Note: This answer assumes that each line corresponds to an element in the vector]

With the statement

```
remove(plan.begin(), plan.end(), "False");
```

you try to remove all elements from the *vector* that are equal to `"False"`.

You need to iterate over the vector and erase the sub-string from each and every string in the vector.

For example you can use a [range `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to iterate over all the strings (or rather *references* to them), and then use the `std::string` functions [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to find the sub-strings you want to remove and [`replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) to replace the sub-strings with empty strings (i.e. nothing).

Comment: I tried something like this with a for loop
`for (int i = 0; i < plan.size(); i++) {
        remove(plan.begin(), plan.end(), "False");
        cout << "Vector: " << plan[i] << endl;}` 
correct me if i'm wrong, but this gave me an error

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is only one occurrence of `"First"` and `"0;0"` in your vector, you can use something like this:

```
std::string EraseFirstSubString(
   const std::string & main_str,
   const std::string & sub_str)
{
   std::string new_main_str = main_str;
   size_t pos = new_main_str.find(sub_str);
   if (pos != std::string::npos)
   {
      new_main_str.erase(pos, sub_str.length());
   }
   return new_main_str;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> plan = {
      "1003;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1678721F",
      "1005;2021-03-05;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1005;2021-03-06;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1003;2021-03-07;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1003;2021-03-08;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1004;2021-03-09;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1004;2021-03-10;False;0;0;1592221D",
      "1001;2021-03-11;False;0;0;1592221D" 
   };

   for (std::string & str : plan)
   {
      str = EraseFirstSubString(str, "False");
      str = EraseFirstSubString(str, "0;0");
   }
};
```

But, if you think that you may have many occurrences of those sub-strings, you should improve a little bit your sub-string removing mechanism like this:

```
std::string EaraseSubStrings(
   const std::string & main_str, 
   const std::string & sub_str)
{
   std::string new_main_str = main_str;
   size_t pos = new_main_str.find(sub_str);

   while (pos != std::string::npos)
   {
      new_main_str.erase(pos, sub_str.length());
      pos = new_main_str.find(sub_str);
   }
   return new_main_str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a vector of individual `std::string` objects, you can easily use the operations that the strings library offers.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// before C++20 change constexpr to inline
constexpr void change(std::vector<std::string>& sv, std::string const& rem) {
  for_each(beign(sv),end(sv), [&rem](std::string& s) {
    s.erase(std::min(s.size(),s.find(rem)), rem.size());
  });
}
```